# C Compiler throwing error: called object ‘random’ is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning C, and have made the following short program. It's supposed to traverse through the array, and assign each element in the array to a random value, then print them out. The only problem is, there's a compiler error stating:

```
called object ‘random’ is not a function or function pointer
```

What is the reason for this? Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int i;
    int random;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            random = rand();
            arr[i] = random();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int random;` shadows the function `long int random(void);` in `stdlib`, which means you're trying to call an integer, which is not a function or a function pointer. Compile with `-Wshadow` on clang or gcc to get warned about this by the compiler. It is unclear whether you intended to use `random()` or not.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings. A modern compiler will warn if enabled properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a variable with the same name as a function you're trying to call.  This "shadows" the function and makes it impossible to call:

```
int random;
```

Quite a common error; a related popular one is when people define a function in their program called `read()` or `send()` which overrides the popular C library functions of the same names.

Answer (score 1):

Since `random` is normal variable having type `int`, you won't need (and mustn't use) `()` operator to use its value.

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int i;
    int random;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            random = rand();
            arr[i] = random;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

or more simple

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            arr[i] = rand();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
            printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```